# Can't run .net project deployed as .zip-package to Azure app service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an `API .net 7.0` project which I am attempting to run as an `Azure web service`. I have a linux app service defined, and I have deployed a zip file created by zipping the output of `dotnet publish` to the service using the command

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group <resource group> --name <app service> --src publish.zip
```

But when I attempt to access the webapp, I simply get

```cs
Your web app is running and waiting for your content.
```

When accessing the webapp using ssh, I can see that `/site/wwwroot` is empty while `/home/Data/SitePackages` contains a zip file.

I have set `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1` under application settings. Startup command is set to `dotnet <name>.dll`

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps to deploy zip package to Azure Linux App service.

- In Visual Studio, Create a `.NET Core 7 API`.
- Open Command Prompt and navigate to the Application Root folder and run the below command.

```cs
dotnet publish
```

[image]

- Folder with name `Publish` will be created in the `bin\Debug\net7.0` folder which contains the `dll` files.
- Select all the files and right click => `Compress to ZIP file`.

[image]

[image]

- In Command Prompt, run the below command to `login to Azure`.

```cs
az login
```

[image]

- In Azure Portal create a `Azure Linux App Service`.

[image]

- Next run the below command to deploy the Application to `Azure Linux App Service`.

```cs
az webapp deploy --resource-group YourRGName --name mywebapp5dec --src-path "C:\*********\source\repos\January\MyCore7App\bin\Debug\net7.0\publish\appsettings.zip"  --target-path "/home/site/wwwroot
```

[image]

***My Folder Structure in `/site/wwwroot` folder:***

[image]

- Access the API.

***OutPut:***
[image]

Comment: it looks like `az webapp deploy` is still in preview based on this warning: `This command is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.msCLI_refstatus` I see in the azure CLI